# Calculate new percentage when new record is added

Tags: php, mysql

I have this MySQL that I am using to calculate a percentage for a segment in a call. When a new record is added, I am able to get the correct percentage for each row.

```
$sumGreeting = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT SUM(greeting_msg + provide_agent_name + clear_and_aud + confirm_caller_name + confirm_caller_tel + ask_alt_number) AS SumGrt  FROM table GROUP BY coach , id");
$sumGreeting->execute();
```

I want to calculate the final percentage each time a new record is added. Taking in mind the previous or existing records. At the moment I'm getting this result below:
[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e90zr.jpg)

I'm using this code

```
            $initRows = 0;
            $result = 0;
            while ($row = $sumGreeting->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                 $initRows = $row['SumGrt'];
                 $result = ($initRows/12)*100;
             echo var_dump($result);
            echo $result ." <br />";    
            }
```

The Expected results will be the final percentage of all the columns.

This section has a total of 12 points.

Thanks in advance

Comment: These are column names in the database. They contain data of type int?